# Converting code from base R to dplyr, specifically adding a variable

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, character, subset

I am trying to add a new variable called "state_color" to the data set "birth_data." I want to streamline my code with dplyr, but I am unsure of how to convert it. I know that in base R it would look like this:

```
red <- c("AK","ID","KS","NE","ND","OK","UT","WY","TX","AL","MS","SC","MT","GA","MO","LA","TN","AK","KY","AZ","WV") 
purple <- c("NC","VA","FL","OH","CO","NV","IN","IA","NM")
blue <- c("NH","PA","CA","MI","IL","MA","DE","NJ","CT","VT","ME","WA","OR","WI","NY","MA","RI","HI","MN","DC")
#assigning states to their respective color

birth_data$state_color[birth_data$state %in% red] <- "red"
birth_data$state_color[birth_data$state %in% purple] <- "purple"
birth_data$state_color[birth_data$state %in% blue] <- "blue"
head(birth_data)
```

I try doing the same with dplyr

```
red <- c("AK","ID","KS","NE","ND","OK","UT","WY","TX","AL","MS","SC","MT","GA","MO","LA","TN","AK","KY","AZ","WV") 
purple <- c("NC","VA","FL","OH","CO","NV","IN","IA","NM")
blue <- c("NH","PA","CA","MI","IL","MA","DE","NJ","CT","VT","ME","WA","OR","WI","NY","MA","RI","HI","MN","DC")
#assigning states to their respective color

birth_data %>%
  mutate(state_color <- c("red","purple","blue"))
```

but then get the error

> Error: Column `state_color <- c("red", "purple", "blue")` must be length 1103629 (the number of rows) or one, not 3

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You want to start with your data set, mutate to create a new column, but then use "case_when". TRUE value is used if all cases fail.

```
red <- c("AK","ID","KS","NE","ND","OK","UT","WY","TX","AL","MS","SC","MT","GA","MO","LA","TN","AK","KY","AZ","WV") 
purple <- c("NC","VA","FL","OH","CO","NV","IN","IA","NM")
blue <- c("NH","PA","CA","MI","IL","MA","DE","NJ","CT","VT","ME","WA","OR","WI","NY","MA","RI","HI","MN","DC")

birth_data %>%
   mutate(state_color =case_when(
       state %in% red  ~ "red",
       state %in% purple  ~ "purple",
       state %in% blue  ~ "blue",
       TRUE ~ "no color"
  ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

birth_data %>%
  mutate(state_color=if_else(state %in% red, "red", if_else(state %in% purple, "purple","blue"))

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) as well if you are looking to expand from base:

```
library(data.table)

dt_states <- data.table(state = state.abb)

dt_states[state %in% red, state_color := 'red']
dt_states[state %in% blue, state_color := 'blue']
dt_states[state %in% purple, state_color := 'purple']

dt_states
```